# Angularjs Factory ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I've been working on a project for a while on my current job and they're using Angulajs for the front-end. Recently I'm trying to implement the ES6 standard. The project uses a Factory to wrap the API services from the backend like this:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('products').factory('Products', ['$resource',
  ($resource)=> {
    return $resource('api/products/:productId', {
      productId: '@id'
    },{
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      },
      getProductsByType : {
        url: 'api/:schoolIdProduct/products/:Type',
        params: {
          schoolIdProduct: ':schoolIdProduct',
          Type: ':Type'
        },
        isArray: true
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

So now right now when we call the Factory from the controller I just add the factory and then call the function like this:

```
$rootScope.supplies = Products.getProducts({
  schoolIdProduct: schoolId,
  Type: 'Supplies'
});
```

So when I try to use the arrow function and `then()` to wait for the response the browser console tells me that is not a function. How do I change my code to use the ES6 standard and get something like this?

```
    Products.getProducts({
      schoolIdProduct: schoolId,
      Type: 'Supplies'
    }).then( (response) =>{
      $rootScope.supplies = response;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

So the thing you are not getting the promise from the response so need to promisify your response either with $q or bluebird.

both solutions are mentioned and you are using ngResource for getting resonses.

angular doc link using $q: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

you may also use bluebird library and convert responses using promise library

```
let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  try {
    resolve(Products.getProducts({
        schoolIdProduct: schoolId,
        Type: 'Supplies'
      })) 
  } catch (error) {
    reject( error)
  }
})
return promise
```

Comment: I alredy tried doing a promise for the response, but it keeps telling me that is not a function.